# error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘LightCount’

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using Gazebo 7 with ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04. I wrote a small gazebo plugin with gets loaded when I load a world in gazebo. However, when I try to use LightCount API, I get the compile error saying "error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘LightCount’".
Here is the link that says that this API is supported
http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1World.html

```
Here is the code snippet that is giving me error
   // Called by the world update start event
    public: void OnUpdate(const common::UpdateInfo & /*_info*/)
    {
       physics::WorldPtr w = this->model->GetWorld();
       unsigned int i = w->LightCount();
       printf("Light count = %d\n", i); 
    }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17369/error:-%E2%80%98class-gazebo::physics::world%E2%80%99-has-no-member-named-%E2%80%98lightcount%E2%80%99/) by [Ash_100](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3901/ash_100/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2017-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What minor version of Gazebo are you running? It looks like `World::LightCount` was added on Gazebo 7.1.0 and is not on 7.0.0.

On Gazebo 7.0.0, you should be able to use `w->Lights().size()` instead.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ash_100](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3901/ash_100/) on 2017-10-02**:
How to update 7.0.0 to 7.1.1? Basically, I want to add/remove lights from the world. Therefore, I need to access API relevant to lights.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-10-02**:
You can follow the instructions here: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=install&tut=install_ubuntu&ver=7.0